# AngularJS Stop Replacement of Default Input Value

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

In AngularJS I have input that is populated by php like so:

```
<form method="post" ng-controller="PostCtrl">
 <input type="text" name="post_title" ng-model="post_title" />
</form>
```

Now in my Controller, I never to specify ng-model, so I lets imagine I have empty controller:

```
EngagementApp.controller('PostCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope) {

    return function($scope) {

    }
}]);
```

The problem I am having is that anything tied to an ng-model automaticcaly gets replaced with an empty value. My question is how can I stop the default php value from being replaced if no value in the controller is set?

Comment: Set the default value in Angular `ng-model="<?php $blah ?>"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-init to set an inital value. For example

```
<input type="text" name="post_title"
 ng-model="post_title" ng-init="post_title='<?$=phpValue;?>'" />
```

The HTML value attribute is ignored by AngularJS.

Comment: If you are supporting users without JavaScript, you will still need to set the `value` attribute. Also, it's good practice to set the scope variable as @gion_13's answer recommends -- I normally initialize it to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You should could the default values from your controller:

```
$scope.post_title = 'default value';
```

But initializing the model from the html by using `ng-init`  ( like @Thomas suggested ) makes more sense in this particular case.